# Parsing a file having content as Json format in Scala

Tags: json, scala, parsing, circe, ujson

I want to parse a file having content as json format.
From the file I want to extract few properties (name, DataType, Nullable) to create some column names dynamically. 
I have gone through some examples but most of them are using case class but my problem is every time I will receive a file may have different content.

I tried to use the **ujson** library to parse the file but I am unable to understand how to use it properly.

```
object JsonTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val source = scala.io.Source.fromFile("C:\\Users\\ktngme\\Desktop\\ass\\file.txt")
    println(source)
    val input = try source.mkString finally source.close()
    println(input)

    val data = ujson.read(input)
    data("name") = data("name").str.reverse
    val updated = data.render()
  }
}
```

**Content of the file example:**

```
{
"Organization": {
"project": {
"name": "POC 4PL",
"description": "Implementation of orderbook"
},
"Entities": [
{
"name": "Shipments",
"Type": "Fact",
"Attributes": [
{
"name": "Shipment_Details",
"DataType": "StringType",
"Nullable": "true"
},
{
"name": "Shipment_ID",
"DataType": "StringType",
"Nullable": "true"
},
{
"name": "View_Cost",
"DataType": "StringType",
"Nullable": "true"
}
],
"ADLS_Location": "/mnt/mns/adls/raw/poc/orderbook/"
}
]
}
}
```

**Expected output:**

```
StructType(
Array(StructField("Shipment_Details",StringType,true),
StructField("Shipment_ID",DateType,true),   
StructField("View_Cost",DateType,true)))
```

StructType needs to be added to the expected output programatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Using Playframework's Json utils - https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/ScalaJson

Here's the solution to your issue- 
\ Placed your json in text file

```
    val fil_path = "C:\\TestData\\Config\\Conf.txt"
    val conf_source = scala.io.Source.fromFile(fil_path)
    lazy val json_str = try conf_source.mkString finally conf_source.close()
    val conf_json: JsValue = Json.parse(json_str)
    val all_entities: JsArray = (conf_json \ "Organization" \ "Entities").get.asInstanceOf[JsArray]
    val shipments: JsValue = all_entities.value.filter(e => e.\("name").as[String] == "Shipments").head
    val shipments_attributes: IndexedSeq[JsValue] = shipments.\("Attributes").get.asInstanceOf[JsArray].value
    val shipments_schema: StructType = StructType(shipments_attributes.map(a => Tuple3(a.\("name").as[String], a.\("DataType").as[String], a.\("Nullable").as[String]))
      .map(x => StructField(x._1, StrtoDatatype(x._2), x._3.toBoolean)))
    shipments_schema.fields.foreach(println)
```

Output is -

```
StructField(Shipment_Details,StringType,true)
StructField(Shipment_ID,StringType,true)
StructField(View_Cost,StringType,true)
```

Comment: Thanks a ton @ValaravausBlack 

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you want it to be completely dynamic or not, here are some options:

If you just want to read one field you can do:

```
import upickle.default._

val source = scala.io.Source.fromFile("C:\\Users\\ktngme\\Desktop\\ass\\file.txt")
val input = try source.mkString finally source.close()
val json = ujson.read(input)

println(json("Organization")("project")("name"))
```

the output will be: `"POC 4PL"`

If you just want just the Attributes to be with types, you can do:

```
import upickle.default.{macroRW, ReadWriter => RW}
import upickle.default._

val source = scala.io.Source.fromFile("C:\\Users\\ktngme\\Desktop\\ass\\file.txt")
val input = try source.mkString finally source.close()
val json = ujson.read(input)
val entitiesArray = json("Organization")("Entities")(0)("Attributes")
println(read[Seq[StructField]](entitiesArray))

case class StructField(name: String, DataType: String, Nullable: String)
object StructField{
  implicit val rw: RW[StructField] = macroRW
}
```

the output will be: `List(StructField(Shipment_Details,StringType,true), StructField(Shipment_ID,StringType,true), StructField(View_Cost,StringType,true))`

another option, is to use a different library to do the class mapping. If you use Google Protobuf [Struct](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/Struct) and [JsonFormat](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/util/JsonFormat) it can be 2-liner:

```
import com.google.protobuf.Struct
import com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat

val source = scala.io.Source.fromFile("C:\\Users\\ktngme\\Desktop\\ass\\file.txt")
val input = try source.mkString finally source.close()

JsonFormat.parser().merge(input, builder)
println(builder.build())
```

the output will be: `fields { key: "Organization" value { struct_value { fields { key: "project" value { struct_value { fields { key: "name" value { string_value: "POC 4PL" } } fields { key: "description" value { string_value: "Implementation of orderbook" } } } } } fields { key: "Entities" value { list_value { values { struct_value { fields { key: "name" value { string_value: "Shipments" } }...`

Comment: Hey @Boaz I didn't understand the Google Protobuf. If I use the first solution then would I be able to extract attributes dynamically? How do I pass the input file path. Can you please share a complete example. Thanks for your support.

Comment: @Stark I added full examples and links to the Google library.

Comment: while executing the above mention program I am getting null pointer exception :( sharing you the exception message.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at ujson.AstTransformer$class.transformObject(AstTransformer.scala:15)
 at ujson.Value$.transformObject(Value.scala:86)
 at ujson.Value$.transform(Value.scala:152)
 at ujson.Value$.transform(Value.scala:86)
 at ujson.AstTransformer$$anonfun$transformArray$1.apply(AstTransformer.scala:11)
 at ujson.AstTransformer$$anonfun$transformArray$1.apply(AstTransformer.scala:11)
 at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)

Comment: at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
 at ujson.AstTransformer$class.transformArray(AstTransformer.scala:11)
 at ujson.Value$.transformArray(Value.scala:86)
 at ujson.Value$.transform(Value.scala:151)
 at ujson.Value$class.transform(Value.scala:75)
 at ujson.Arr.transform(Value.scala:211)
 at upickle.Api$class.read(Api.scala:32)
 at upickle.default$.read(Api.scala:102)
 at StructField$.delayedEndpoint$StructField$1(StructField.scala:18)
 at StructField$delayedInit$body.apply(StructField.scala:10)

Comment: at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
 at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
 at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
 at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
 at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
 at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
 at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
 at StructField$.main(StructField.scala:10)
 at StructField.main(StructField.scala)

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: import upickle.default.{macroRW, ReadWriter => RW}
import upickle.default._

case class StructField(name: String, DataType: String, Nullable: String)

object StructField extends App {

val source = scala.io.Source.fromFile("C:\\Users\\ktngme\\Desktop\\ass\\file.txt")
val input = try source.mkString finally source.close()
val json = ujson.read(input)
val entitiesArray = json("Organization")("Entities")(0)("Attributes")
println(read[Seq[StructField]](entitiesArray))

implicit val rw: RW[StructField] = macroRW

}

Comment: I run the above code with `input` equal to what you put in the question under `Content of the file example`. try not to read the json from file, put it hardcoded just to make sure all the ujson part is working

Comment: I must have to pass the Json content through file. And if I pass the content as hard-coded hen it will not be a generic solution.

Comment: I meant only for you to fined the root cause of the problem. read file to string is one problem, and deserialize json to object is a different problem. for me the example above works